# Gcc error while compiling option -fPIC

Tags: objective-c, ios, gcc

I'm reading a book but I get one error while compiling with this code.

```
$ rm -f injection.dylib
$ export PLATFORM=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
$ $PLATFORM/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 \
-c -o injection.o injection.c \
-isysroot $PLATFORM/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk \ -fPIC
$ $PLATFORM/Developer/usr/bin/ld \ -dylib -lsystem -lobjc \
-o injection.dylib injection.o \
-syslibroot $PLATFORM/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/
```

I've some trouble especially in this line:

```
$PLATFORM/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 \
-c -o injection.o injection.c \
-isysroot $PLATFORM/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk \ -fPIC
```

This is the error

```
 arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2:  -fPIC: No such file or directory
```

how can I solve... what does it means?

Answer (score 2):

It means you mistyped the command line:

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ gcc \ -fPIC
gcc: error:  -fPIC: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Seems the \ in the middle of the line makes gcc (and probably the llvm-gcc as well) stop considering arguments as options and always treats them as filenames.

```
stieber@gatekeeper:~$ gcc -fPIC
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

gives the expected result.

Comment: Very interesting; it does indeed do that.  Almost as if a backslash on its own '``\``' (See [How do you type a single backslash code formatted in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129704/how-do-you-type-a-single-backslash-code-formatted-in-a-comment)) were a surrogate for '`--`' which traditionally marks the end of options and beginning of file arguments (for most commands; compilers generally interleave files and options anyway).

Comment: thank you for the answer but I can't understand how must be the query to compile the code.